# Cart emptying after logging in to Magento

Tags: magento

I am facing with an `intermittent empty cart issue` with my **Magento (ver. 1.12.0.2)**. When a customer add products to the cart and proceed to checkout page he will be asked to login; once enter the credentials and login to the page, immediately he will be redirected to `cart empty` page. I have **cleared my APC and Magento cache**; still this issue persists; can anybody please suggest cause of this behavior ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IQbalmp,it can be cookie issue.
Please check  cookie domain from `admin>system/Configutation>Web>cookie management`.

Also,check you browser setting.